# Error: 'list' object is not callable, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on python, for a test, and create this code for a quest
I need the code to read two files, order the first one from largest to smallest, and then see which ones are in the other file, with that create another file in which are repeated in both files and sorted
Example:

First text:

```
Git-gud,-32
Hogwarts Great hall Wifi,-67
God is my rock,-56
Interwebz,-75
OptimusPrime,-32
gg-wp,-53
UdeS-Alumnos,-90
```

Second text:

```
Que-sucede
Get-off-my-lawn
Git-gud
gg-wp
All the pancakes
My-name-is-lucifer
Optimus-prime
Hogwarts Great hall Wifi
```

Third text:

```
Git-gud,-32
OptimusPrime,-32
gg-wp,-53
Hogwarts Great hall Wifi,-67
```

When I try to create the list with the networks of the third file, the error appears

I don't know what is wrong

```py
def redes(contenido, guardadas):
    redes=[]
    i=0
    while i<len(contenido):
        j=0
        while j<len(guardadas):
            if contenido[i][0]==guardadas[j]:
                redes.append(contenido[i])
            j=j+1
        i=i+1
    return redes
```

when i start the code this error appears

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/basty/Desktop/all/Guia y soluciones/textos/Wi-Fi/1.py", line 66, in <module>
    disponibles=redes(redesOrdenadas, guardadas)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

This is my code

```
#Wi-Fi
#Función que lee los archivos
def leer(texto):
    texto=texto+'.txt'
    archivo= open(texto,'r')
    contenido= []
    for linea in archivo:
        contenido.append(linea.strip('\n'))
    archivo.close
    return contenido
#Función quitar las comas
def sinComas(contenido):
    i=0
    sinComas=[]
    while i <len(contenido):
        sinComas = sinComas + [contenido[i].split(',')]
        i=i+1
    return sinComas
#Función ordenar por señal
def ordenar(contenido):
    i=0
    while i<len(contenido):
        j=i+1
        while j<len(contenido):
            if int(contenido[i][1])<int(contenido[j][1]):
                aux=contenido[i]
                contenido[i]=contenido[j]
                contenido[j]=aux
            j+=1
        i+=1
    return contenido
#Función guardar redes disponibles para conectar
def redesDisponibles(contenido, guardadas):
    redes=[]
    i=0
    while i<len(contenido):
        j=0
        while j<len(guardadas):
            if contenido[i][0]==guardadas[j]:
                redes.append(contenido[i])
            j=j+1
        i=i+1
    return redes
#Función agregar comas
def agregarComas(redes):
    i=0
    conComas=''
    escribir=[]
    while i<len(redes):
        j=0
        while j<len(redes[i]):
            conComas=','.join(redes[i])
            j=j+1
        escribir.append(conComas+'\n')
        i=i+1
    return escribir
#Función escribir
def escribir(texto):
    return True
#Bloque Principal
#Entrada
redesEncontradas=leer('signal-strenght')
guardadas= leer('networks')
#Proceso
sinComas=sinComas(redesEncontradas)
redesOrdenadas=ordenar(sinComas)
disponibles=redes(redesOrdenadas, guardadas)
conComas=agregarComas(disponibles)
```

Comment: Don't use the same name (``redes``) for your method and for your local variable.

Comment: I changed the names of the variables and the function and the error continues

Comment: in  the main script, you have defined a variable named `redes` and its a list object. this override the function name `redes`. change it.

Comment: You didn't show the code from which this error is raised which makes it harder to help

Comment: I show the code below, I changed variables and fuction names, but it does not solve it

Comment: tons of bad naming convention, you should prefer not to use path with "space", or just a digit as filename, and as @MikeScotty told, redes is both a function name or a variable name, you could not apply `()` on a list

Answer (score 0):

Mike Scotty pointed out your main problem: naming a var the same as the method. I also would suggest a list comprehension like this:

```
return [x for x in contenido if x in guardadas]
```

Eliminating the need for a named variable.

If I have the text inputs provided I can simply do this:

```
t1 = '''Git-gud,-32
Hogwarts Great hall Wifi,-67
God is my rock,-56
Interwebz,-75
OptimusPrime,-32
gg-wp,-53
UdeS-Alumnos,-90'''
```

and

```
t2 = '''Que-sucede
Get-off-my-lawn
Git-gud
gg-wp
All the pancakes
My-name-is-lucifer
Optimus-prime
Hogwarts Great hall Wifi'''
```

then

```
result = [x for x in t1.split('\n') if x.split(',')[0] in t2.split('\n')]
```

result looks like:

```
['Git-gud,-32', 'Hogwarts Great hall Wifi,-67', 'gg-wp,-53']
```

Comment: like this ```def redesDisponibles(contenido, guardadas):
    return [x for x in contenido if x in guardadas]``` ?
i use that and the error continues

Comment: Python handles a lot of things for you. Google "list comprehensions" and "context handlers". This will save you tons of lines of code. I will update my answer with some code to work with your two text inputs. I get one less result in the output. Does the Optimus Prime part care about dashes?